# R, interval, mutate

Tags: r, sorting, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a dataset about animals.

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- c("Date", "Specie", "Number")
b <- c("2020-01-01", "Dog", "3")
c <- c("2020-01-02", "Dog", "4")
d <- c("2020-01-03", "Dog", "5")
e <- c("2020-01-04", "Dog", "6")
f <- c("2020-01-01", "Cat", "3")
g <- c("2020-01-02", "Cat", "7")
h <- c("2020-01-03", "Cat", "8")
i <- c("2020-01-04", "Cat", "10")

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i))
names(df) <- a
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
df$Number <- as.integer(df$Number)

start <- as.Date("2020-01-02")
end <- as.Date("2020-01-04")

df %>%
  filter(Date >= start & Date <= end) %>%
  group_by(Specie) %>% 
  summarise(new = prod(10 + Number), .groups = "drop")
```

The goal is to create a new variable that gives me: (using tidyverse)
For each specie, between 2020-01-02 and 2020-01-04 (included), I want a new variable that is the product of (10+number of dead animals that day).
For-example, for dogs it would be (10+4)*(10+5)*(10+6).
Same for all specie.

Please note that for some specie, I don't have the number of dead animals during all the days of the interval.

- Is dropping them the best option?
  If yes, how do you do it.

Note that the code filters and hence keeps only my dataset for the dates specify. I want to return the output that the code delivers but in my original dataset.

- That is, the output I get should be a new variable (mutate) for all species. And not a subset of my dataset.
  I did a left-join to merge the original dataset with the new (filtered) one. It works, but I think there's a more efficient way.

Thank's for your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there are some numbers missing in `Number`, I could think of three ways for handling those missing values:

1. Set them to `NA` and use `prod(..., na.rm = TRUE)` to remove them in the calculation of the product.
2. Set them to `0` and use `prod(..., na.rm = FALSE)` to at least inflate the product by a factor of `10`.
3. If you want to preserve some mean (arithmetic or geometric) of the factors (10+a_i), set the missing values to that mean minus 10.

In cases 2 and 3 you can for example give a lower bound for the product: prod >= 10^n. (Taking the logarithm to base 10 on both sides yields log(prod) = sum(log) >= n.) But maybe you want to reserve case 2 for those rows that really have zero dead animals.

Regarding your second point, use `mutate` with `ifelse` to flag your wanted dates (instead of `filter`) and additionally group by this new flag. Then use again `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

```
df %>% mutate(
  new = ifelse(Date >= start & Date <= end, 1, NA)
) %>% group_by(
  Specie, 
  new
) %>% mutate(
  new = ifelse(!is.na(new), prod(10 + Number, na.rm = FALSE), new)
)
```